# While Loop output data live (VB.net) XML Reader

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, while-loop, reader

**Background Story:** I have a huge XML file (about 57 GB and increasing about 250 MB / week) which i need to read through and parse data to a database. So far I've been able to setup a XML reader in a while loop which can read each element at a time and output the data I need. I've also added an element counter and a limit of 600 elements in the loop. This works perfect and I'm able to get the first 600 elements of the total of 8.7 million elements in about 2sec. Then I changed the limit to loop the first 2000 elements and now it had to run for 20 sec. At 3000 elements it took almost 50 sec but the estimate from the first test showed it should have taking only 10 sec.

I've noticed that the while loop waits for the all the elements to run through before it displays it in my application. When I press the button nothing happens until all the data is ready. This is probably why it's getting exponentially slower and slower, as the application has to store each variable somewhere while the loop is active. The intention of the XML reader was to not store all the information in memory at once, but it looks like thats exactly whats it's doing now anyways.

**QUESTION:** *Is there someway i can force the application to output the data to a database after each loop and therefore don't have to store anything in memory?*

Here is my XML and the Vb.net code I've modified to my project. I can post my exact code if you need it, but it's very similair:

XML:

```
<reflection><apis>
<api id="M:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(System.String,System.Int32)">
  <apidata name="Mid" group="member" subgroup="method" />
  <containers>
    <namespace api="N:Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <type api="T:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings" ref="true" />
  </containers>
</api> 
<api id="M:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32)">
  <apidata name="Mid" group="member" subgroup="method" />
  <containers>
    <namespace api="N:Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <type api="T:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings" ref="true" />
  </containers>
</api></apis></reflection>
```

Button Click:

```
        Dim reader = Xml.XmlReader.Create("..\..\reflectionData.xml")
    reader.MoveToContent()

    While reader.ReadToFollowing("api")
        Dim api = TryCast(XElement.ReadFrom(reader), XElement)

        If api Is Nothing Then Continue While

        ' Get information from the <api> element.
        Dim ns = api.<containers>.<namespace>.@api
        Dim containingType = api.<containers>.<type>.@api
    End While

    reader.Close()
```

Comment: Is this the real code that you are using? Or are you also writing the data to the database inside the loop? How are you sure that the XML reading part is the one that is slowing you down?

Comment: Use XmlTextReader instead of XmlReader.  Text Reader is equivalent but "Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data."  It may solve your issue.